# Completely reset mysql server authentication

Tags: security, mysql

I was trying to change the password for a user on a mysql server, and i appear to have locked myself out.

I have access to the root user, but root doesn't have the privileges to access any databses, including the 'mysql' database where all the config is kept.

Is there any way i can 'reset' the root user? (i have full file-system access) 
... or do i just need to reinstall (can i salvage my data?)

Thanks.
-Ped

Answer (score 4):

I believe that restarting MySQL with the [--skip-grant-tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-grant-tables) options will allow you to enter the database as root, where you can then fix the permissions in the mysql and all other databases.

This is sorta, kinda similar to resetting the root password if you forgot it:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html